# Getting true valid number using asYouType in libphonenumber when its invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, libphonenumber

I'm using libphonenumber in react to format and validate phone number (Lebanese number in my case).

The valid mask of the Lebanese phone number is +961 xx xxx xxx
and that's actually working well in the example given in their demo
 [Here](https://catamphetamine.github.io/libphonenumber-js)

so for Lebanon the country code is `LB` and valid template is `xx xxx xxx`

so for example When the input is `+961 71 123 123` ==> phone number is actually `valid` and `+961 71 123 12` is not

in my case in react the input number is valid once it reaches `2` as in `71 123 12` when it supposed to reach `3`

```
import { AsYouType } from 'libphonenumber-js'

let asYouType = new AsYouType()

asYouType.defaultCountry = 'LB';
asYouType.reset();

asYouType.input('7112312')

// <<< PROBLEM HERE >>>
console.log('number is valid ',asYouType.getNumber().isValid()); 
//output: is valid when it should not be valid 71 123 12 (missing     one number)


asYouType.defaultCountry = 'LB';
asYouType.reset();
asYouType.input('711231') 
console.log('number is valid ',asYouType.getNumber().isValid()); 
// out : false (OK)

asYouType.defaultCountry = 'LB';
asYouType.reset();
asYouType.input('71123123') 
console.log('number is valid ',asYouType.getNumber().isValid()); 
// out: true (OK)
```

Comment: Is this considering South Lebanon? I've found that those numbers can only have 10 total digits instead of your 11.

Comment: @YannickK actually , the landline and other numbers that begin with a 0 are considered 10, and they are actually valid (01,04,05 landline) or (03 mobile). for example the demo in their website (10 numbers are valid in that case) else my examlpe of 71 123 12 is not valid which is true (**asYouType** example demo [Here](https://catamphetamine.github.io/libphonenumber-js))

Comment: @YannickK (03,01,04,07 etc) can be written without the leading 0 by the way hence the 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

*libphonenumber-js* by default uses a reduced metadata set in order to reduce the package size. What you see might be a result of that simplification.

If you want to use the full metadata set, use the **`/max`** suffix when importing the library.

```
import { AsYouType } from 'libphonenumber-js/max'
```

Check the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js#min-vs-max-vs-mobile-vs-core) for further information about the provided metadata sets.